# How can I switch to the new open page after click button register? C# Selenium specflow

Tags: c#, selenium

so I'm a newbie in C# selenium and I faced one problem(issue) I create several steps on one main page after I add information on the registration page I click to "register button" and this redirects me to the next new page, and my test cases failed. Because my webDriver is still on the previous page. But I should find a new element on a new page.
How can I do it more simple way? Thank you in advance.

```
        [When(@"I add specific name")]
        public void WhenIAddSpecificName()
        {
            namelField.Click();
            namelField.Clear();
            Random randomName = new Random();
            int randomNumName = randomName.Next(0, 10000);
            namelField.SendKeys($"IK" + randomNumName);
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            
        }

        [Then(@"I click registration button")]
        public void ThenIClickRegistrationButton()
        {
            registrationButton.Click();
            webDriver.SwitchTo().Window(webDriver.WindowHandles[1]);


        }

        [When(@"I add mobile telephone no")]
        public void WhenIAddMobileTelephoneNo()
        {            
            phoneField.Click();
            phoneField.SendKeys("2222");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            webDriver.Close();
        }
```

I want to find a new element on the new page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably get all the handles before switching to it using `driver.WindowHandles`

So once you've performed a click then you should use the below code:

```
registrationButton.Click();
List<string> winodws = new List<string>(driver.WindowHandles);
driver.SwitchTo().Window(winodws[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.I'll try to do it tomorrow. And leave some comments.

Comment: Hello, @cruisepandey!  I think I miss something, I add your code into mu, but I have some error related to  "tabs" what should I do?

Comment: @Ilja: It should have been `driver.SwitchTo().Window(winodws[1]);` not tabs[1], Please see above.

Comment: Message: 
OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException : element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=99.0.4844.82)

  Stack Trace: 
WebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
WebDriver.InternalExecute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
WebElement.Execute(String commandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
WebElement.SendKeys(String text)

Comment: @Ilja: This is a whole new error, I'd suggest you open a new ticket for this issue. This is SO guidelines.